# React native PureComponent anti-pattern

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

Objects/Arrays/Functions created in render are a performance anti pattern, e.g.: 
https://medium.com/@esamatti/react-js-pure-render-performance-anti-pattern-fb88c101332f

My question, is this also true for "style"? Would this re-render the child if the class re-renders?

```
class Test extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <View style={{width:100,height:100}} />
  }
}
```